# Get value from a certain row in a column

Tags: php, phpexcel

I currently have the below code that will loop through the excel file and return rows with missing data. the output is as below:

```
- Row number: 37
    - Missing : in cell B37
    - Missing : in cell D37
```

What I would like to return is the following

```
- Row number: 37
    - Missing nameFirst : in cell B37
    - Missing nameLast : in cell D37
```

Where nameFirst is the value of cell B1 and nameLast is the value of D1.

```
<?PHP
require_once 'Excel/PHPExcel.php';
require_once 'Excel/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php';
class MyReadFilter implements PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter
{
    public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName = '') {
        $Retour=false;
        $column=PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($column);// Warning ! A=1, not zero as usual
        if($row<1 || $column>4)
            $Retour=false;
        else
            $Retour=true;
        return $Retour;
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$objReader->setReadFilter( new MyReadFilter() );
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load('test.xlsx');
$worksheet=$objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
        if($row->getRowIndex()>1){
            echo '    - Row number: ' . $row->getRowIndex() . "\r\n";

            $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
            $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false); // Loop all cells, even if it is not set
            foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
                 $colIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($cell->getColumn());



                if($cell->getCalculatedValue() == "")
                echo '        - Missing <THIS IS WHERE I WANT THE INDEX CELL FOR THE COLUMN> :' . 'in cell ' . $cell->getCoordinate() . "\r\n";

        }
        }
    }
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

I tried changing the echo to include the variable $colIndex in addition to:

```
            echo '        - Missing '. $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($colIndex, 1)->getValue(). '. :'  . $cell->getCoordinate() . "\r\n";
```

But this causes a return of one row and only one correct cell and a whole bunch of blank variables

```
- Row number: 2
    - Missing nameFirst. :B1
    - Missing . :E1
    - Missing . :F1
    - Missing . :G1
    - Missing . :H1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need to get the cell value for row 1 in the current cell's ($cell) column

```
echo '        - Missing ' .
     $worksheet->getCell($cell->getColumn(). '1')->getValue() . 
     ' :' . 'in cell ' . 
     $cell->getCoordinate() . "\r\n";
```

should work perfectly well